# How to Compare Two Algorithms with Multiple Datasets and Multiple Runs

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, repeated-measures

I have two computational methods (A and B) that have a random behavior each, i.e., if you run the same methods 10 times, you get 10 different results (usually with a small variance). To compare both methods, we selected 5 different databases (its hard to get more) and ran method A and method B, 10 times each, on each of the five databases. This resulted in a `10x5` matrix of measurements (a row for each run and a column for each database) for each method. All measurements are paired between the two methods, because we can control the seed for each run and the database can be reused for both methods, i.e., $\text{run}_i$ of $\text{database}_j$ use the same $\text{seed}_i$ for both methods.

Example (the values in the tables are the accuracies of the methods):

#### Method A

```
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Run/Database|   1    |   2    |   3    |   4    |   5    |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|           1 | 88.92% | 44.60% | 69.49% | 73.37% | 85.63% |
|           2 | 89.00% | 42.72% | 64.10% | 71.94% | 85.92% |
|           3 | 88.35% | 45.07% | 65.13% | 72.14% | 85.78% |
|           4 | 88.92% | 43.66% | 67.95% | 72.76% | 85.28% |
|           5 | 87.94% | 50.23% | 67.18% | 71.94% | 85.92% |
|           6 | 87.78% | 43.19% | 68.72% | 73.47% | 86.27% |
|           7 | 89.08% | 45.54% | 66.41% | 71.33% | 85.56% |
|           8 | 88.83% | 42.72% | 66.15% | 72.45% | 86.77% |
|           9 | 88.43% | 45.07% | 68.97% | 72.45% | 86.49% |
|          10 | 88.59% | 40.38% | 66.15% | 73.67% | 86.13% |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

#### Method B

```
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Run/Database|   1    |   2    |   3    |   4    |   5    |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|           1 | 22.73% | 53.99% | 59.74% | 65.20% | 79.59% |
|           2 | 75.97% | 46.95% | 58.46% | 71.63% | 84.42% |
|           3 | 76.94% | 53.05% | 58.97% | 68.37% | 85.06% |
|           4 | 76.54% | 42.25% | 46.67% | 68.67% | 85.92% |
|           5 | 46.60% | 52.11% | 52.82% | 68.98% | 85.14% |
|           6 | 76.78% | 48.83% | 55.90% | 68.27% | 78.38% |
|           7 | 79.37% | 47.89% | 58.72% | 71.12% | 85.06% |
|           8 | 77.83% | 54.93% | 50.77% | 72.14% | 87.06% |
|           9 | 83.01% | 46.95% | 56.15% | 67.96% | 84.92% |
|          10 | 78.24% | 49.30% | 58.21% | 67.96% | 81.29% |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Which statistical method shall I use to find out which method is the best in terms of overall performance? Or to find out if method A is statistically different, in terms of average accuracy, from method B?

I investigated the use of Student T-Test and One and Two-Way ANOVA with Repeated Measurements, but they didn't seem appropriate for this analysis. Any suggestion of valid statistical analysis is appreciated.

Comment: What would "best" mean in this context? Do you want a higher mean, or lower variance, or something else?

Comment: @gung by "best" I mean, if the difference between them is statistically significant, I assume it is correct to consider the method with higher mean as the best one. Is it correct or should I consider something else?

Comment: Difference between them *in what* is statistically significant? Note that even if they differ significantly in some way, that doesn't necessarily mean that one or the other is "best".

Comment: @gung The difference in terms of the overall performance (the values in the table are the accuracy of each method for a specific run in a specific database). I would like to be able to say that one method presents higher accuracy, on average, than the other, taking the paired runs and multiple datasets into account.

Answer (score 4):

There is a paper which concretely studies this question in detail ([Statistical Comparisons of Classifiers over Multiple Data Sets](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/demsar06a/demsar06a.pdf)) with pretty sobering conclusions.

It is actually very tricky. As you note, your methods are not deterministic and yield a different result each time. That means that in some cases, A might be better than B by pure chance, but if you run the test several times, in average, B might be better than A.

Regardless of the random behaviour of your methods, by testing two methods over different databases, sometimes A will be better than B and viceversa by chance. There is no universally better algorithm. Another way to look at it is: it makes no sense to compare tests obtained with the same methods on different data sets if they are not commensurate.

The basic takeaway message of the paper is that, if you cannot guarantee that the assumptions made by parametric tests are fulfilled (be it ANOVA or t-test), then it is better to make use of non-parametric tests (Wilcoxon test of Friedman's test). And that seems to be indeed your case. See also these [slides](http://www.icmla-conference.org/icmla11/PE_Tutorial.pdf), specially #34, for a very nice summary.

Answer (score 3):

## There are some issues.

### regarding your question

A) It might be that one test performs better on average, but is less consistent either varying a lot for different databases, or varying a low for different runs (the latter problem, if it is important, might be solved by using an average of multiple runs). You would have to define the acceptable boundaries or a way to rank the algorithms using these multiple aspects

### improvements of your current experimental method

B) You might be able to generate fake databases, or if not desired possibly take the existing databases and see how performance varies as a function of database size, unbalance, amount of noise, different training sets etcetera.

C) You might take a more analytical approach and calculate directly the expected distribution of performance for your stochastic algoritm, or at least make educated guesses.

## Statistical tests

From a hypothesis testing point of view H(A = B) it doesn't make sense, *to me*, to do calculations. It is already clear (see Image 1) that method A performs uniformly better on databases 1,3,4, and 5 and B is better on database 2 which seems to be the toughest database (so you could say that B does better on the though problems and A better on the simple problems). So there is no database the best in everything, at least based on what you can guess from 5 databases, and it depends on what you want.

## Possible Bayesian approach

There are various schemes to still do 'some' calculation. There might be a lot of literature about that.

Something basic that I just created by hand (I am not a professional in this but it may work for you) is a scheme in which you...

1) *assume* a beta distribution for the chance that you will get a certain performance on the average of ten results.

2) Then calculate the likelihood for the various distributions. (see Images 2 and 3)

3) Then based on that likelihood distribution calculate the expected chance for a certain performance outcome. (using an a-priori expectation for the space of parameters of the beta distribution that is uniform (see Image 4)

*Since this output in figure 4 looks again much like a beta-distribution, I can imagine that some mathematician might come up with a more direct calculation using some properties of beta-distributions and how they mix or convolve.*

## Images

Figure 1) Graphical view of the performance as a function of the rank of the run
[image: Graphical view of the performance as a function of the rank of the run]

Figure 2) log-likelihood for beta distribution parameters of performance of model A
[image: log-likelihood for beta distribution parameters of performance of model A]

Figure 3) log-likelihood for beta distribution parameters of performance of model B
[image: log-likelihood for beta distribution parameters of performance of model A]

Figure 4) estimates of distribution of performance
*notice the tail at the low end for the model A, which relates to the lower performance of model A on the 2nd database*
[image: estimates of distribution of performance]

## Code

below is some sloppy r-code to generate the images 
(note: I did not check the libraries that you need to load)

```
> ########## data
method_a = matrix(c(88.92, 44.60, 69.49, 73.37, 85.63,
             89.00, 42.72, 64.10, 71.94, 85.92,
             88.35, 45.07, 65.13, 72.14, 85.78,
             88.92, 43.66, 67.95, 72.76, 85.28,
             87.94, 50.23, 67.18, 71.94, 85.92,
             87.78, 43.19, 68.72, 73.47, 86.27,
             89.08, 45.54, 66.41, 71.33, 85.56,
             88.83, 42.72, 66.15, 72.45, 86.77,
             88.43, 45.07, 68.97, 72.45, 86.49,
             88.59, 40.38, 66.15, 73.67, 86.13),10,byrow=1)

method_b = matrix(c(22.73, 53.99, 59.74, 65.20, 79.59,
             75.97, 46.95, 58.46, 71.63, 84.42,
             76.94, 53.05, 58.97, 68.37, 85.06,
             76.54, 42.25, 46.67, 68.67, 85.92,
             46.60, 52.11, 52.82, 68.98, 85.14,
             76.78, 48.83, 55.90, 68.27, 78.38,
             79.37, 47.89, 58.72, 71.12, 85.06,
             77.83, 54.93, 50.77, 72.14, 87.06,
             83.01, 46.95, 56.15, 67.96, 84.92,
             78.24, 49.30, 58.21, 67.96, 81.29),10,byrow=1)

########## plot ordered graphs
layout(matrix(1:5,1))
for (i in 1:5) {
  plot(1:10,method_a[order(method_a[,i]),i],pch=21,col=3,bg=3,ylim=c(0,100),xlab=c("","","test ranking","","")[i],ylab=c("performance","","","","")[i])
  points(1:10,method_b[order(method_b[,i]),i],pch=21,col=2,bg=2)
  lines(1:10,method_b[order(method_b[,i]),i],col=2)
  lines(1:10,method_a[order(method_a[,i]),i],col=1)
  title(paste0("database ",i))
}

legend(5,24, c("model A", "model B"), col = c(3, 2), pt.bg=c(3,2),
       lty = c(1, 1), pch = c(21,21))


########## calculate log likelihood for betadistribution parameters

layout(matrix(c(1:2),2))

# initial parameters
f_a <- colMeans(method_a)
p_a<-matrix(rep(1,300*300),300) #distribution function
x_a<-matrix(rep(1,300*300),300) #area function

a_range <- 10^seq(-3,3,length.out=300)
b_range <- 10^seq(-3,3,length.out=300)

# probabilities
for (n_a in 1:300) {
  for (n_b in 1:300) {
    alpha <- a_range[n_a] 
    beta <- b_range[n_b]
    ps <- dbeta(f_a/100,alpha,beta)/100
    p_a[n_a,n_b] <- ps[1]*ps[2]*ps[3]*ps[4]*ps[5]
    x_a[n_a,n_b] <- a_range[n_a]*b_range[n_b]*log(10)^2*(6/300)^2
  }
}

# normalization
p_a<-p_a/sum(p_a*x_a)

# contour plot
filled.contour(x=log(a_range,10),y=log(b_range,10),z=log(p_a,10),
               xlab="log(alpha)",ylab="log(beta)",         
               levels=c(-500,-400,-300,-200,-100,-10:-1),
               color.palette=function(n) {hsv(seq(0.15,0.7,length.out=n),seq(0.7,0.2,length.out=n),seq(1,0.7,length.out=n))},
               plot.axes= c({
                 contour(x=log(a_range,10),y=log(b_range,10),z=log(p_a,10),add=1,levels=c(-500,-400,-300,-200,-100,-10:-1),)
                 title("log-likelihood beta distribution parameters for model a")
                 axis(1)
                 axis(2)
               },"")
)

########## calculate log likelihood for beta distribution parameters

# initial parameters
f_b <- colMeans(method_b)
p_b<-matrix(rep(1,300*300),300)
x_b<-matrix(rep(1,300*300),300)

a_range <- 10^seq(-3,3,length.out=300)
b_range <- 10^seq(-3,3,length.out=300)

# probabilities
for (n_a in 1:300) {
  for (n_b in 1:300) {
    alpha <- a_range[n_a] 
    beta <- b_range[n_b]
    ps <- dbeta(f_b/100,alpha,beta)/100
    p_b[n_a,n_b] <- ps[1]*ps[2]*ps[3]*ps[4]*ps[5]
    x_b[n_a,n_b] <- a_range[n_a]*b_range[n_b]*log(10)^2*(6/300)^2
  }
}

# normalization
p_b<-p_b/sum(p_b*x_b)

# contour plot
filled.contour(x=log(a_range,10),y=log(b_range,10),z=log(p_b,10),
               xlab="log(alpha)",ylab="log(beta)",         
               levels=c(-500,-400,-300,-200,-100,-10:-1),
               color.palette=function(n) {hsv(seq(0.15,0.7,length.out=n),seq(0.7,0.2,length.out=n),seq(1,0.7,length.out=n))},
               plot.axes= c({
                 contour(x=log(a_range,10),y=log(b_range,10),z=log(p_b,10),add=1,levels=c(-500,-400,-300,-200,-100,-10:-1),)
                 title("log-likelihood beta-distribution parameters for model b")
                 axis(1)
                 axis(2)
               },"")
)



# calculate estimates for model A
px_a <- rep(0,100)
for (n_a in 1:300) {
  for (n_b in 1:300) {
    alpha <- a_range[n_a] 
    beta <- b_range[n_b]
      for (x in 1:100)  {
          p <- dbeta(x/100-0.5/100,alpha,beta)*p_a[n_a,n_b]*x_a[n_a,n_b]*(1/100)
          px_a[x] <- px_a[x]  +  p

      }
  }
}

#calculate estimates for model B
px_b <- rep(0,100)
for (n_a in 1:300) {
  for (n_b in 1:300) {
    alpha <- a_range[n_a] 
    beta <- b_range[n_b]
    for (x in 1:100)  {
      p <- dbeta(x/100-0.5/100,alpha,beta)*p_b[n_a,n_b]*x_b[n_a,n_b]*(1/100)
      px_b[x] <- px_b[x]  +  p

    }
  }
}

#plotting estimates for model A and B
layout(matrix(1))
plot(px_a,type="l",col=3,ylim=c(0,0.04),xlab="performance",ylab="frequency")
title("beta-distribution based expected frequency distribution for mean of 10 trials")
lines(px_b,col=2)
legend(1,0.04, c("model A", "model B"), col = c(3, 2), pt.bg=c(3,2),
       lty = c(1, 1), pch = c(21,21))

sum(px_a)
sum(px_b)
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a mixed effect model, with accuracy as the outcome. You can enter database and run as random effects, and model (A or B) as a fixed effect. This will tell you whether there is any significant difference in accuracy between models A and B and, if so, which model has higher accuracy. Note that database and run need to be entered as factors (categorical variables), not numeric variables (continuous).

In R:

```
# make the dataframe
mydata <- structure(list(Model = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c(" A", 
" B"), class = "factor"), Run = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "factor"), Data = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    Accuracy = c(88.92, 89, 88.35, 88.92, 87.94, 87.78, 89.08, 
    88.83, 88.43, 88.59, 22.73, 75.97, 76.94, 76.54, 46.6, 76.78, 
    79.37, 77.83, 83.01, 78.24, 44.6, 42.72, 45.07, 43.66, 50.23, 
    43.19, 45.54, 42.72, 45.07, 40.38, 53.99, 46.95, 53.05, 42.25, 
    52.11, 48.83, 47.89, 54.93, 46.95, 49.3, 69.49, 64.1, 65.13, 
    67.95, 67.18, 68.72, 66.41, 66.15, 68.97, 66.15, 59.74, 58.46, 
    58.97, 46.67, 52.82, 55.9, 58.72, 50.77, 56.15, 58.21, 73.37, 
    71.94, 72.14, 72.76, 71.94, 73.47, 71.33, 72.45, 72.45, 73.67, 
    65.2, 71.63, 68.37, 68.67, 68.98, 68.27, 71.12, 72.14, 67.96, 
    67.96, 85.63, 85.92, 85.78, 85.28, 85.92, 86.27, 85.56, 86.77, 
    86.49, 86.13, 79.59, 84.42, 85.06, 85.92, 85.14, 78.38, 85.06, 
    87.06, 84.92, 81.29)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Model", 
"Run", "Data", "Accuracy"), row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

Run the model:

```
library(lme4)
m1 <- lmer(Accuracy ~ Model + (1 | Data) + (1 | Run), data = mydata)
```

Note: Because accuracy is bounded at 0 and 1 (or 0 and 100, if you express it as percent), technically you may want to use a link function that will take that into account, for example, logistic regression. Generalized models with random effects can be a pain to estimate, though, so you may prefer to treat accuracy as a regular continuous outcome. By eyeballing your data, my guess is that you'll be okay with a regular mixed effects model, without using a logistic link function --- your accuracy scores are not clustered too closely to either bound, so they're probably more or less normally distributed, or at least closely enough that you'll get sensible estimates from your model.

Comment: +1. This is an insightful answer; if anything it reminds me of some adaptive training/resampling procedure I have come across in the past that relied on the concept of [futility analysis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.6974.pdf) and [Bradley-Terry models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley%E2%80%93Terry_model). Just side-question: Why define `Model` as a random slope? What's the slope for? Granted you might want to consider a `Data\Model` nesting but that's another thing from the current suggestion. (Sorry I missed commented and voting before the bounty closed.)

Comment: @usεr11852 Good call --- in this case, it actually probably makes the most sense not to get a random effect for model (assuming OP just wants to analyze these two particular models and isn't interested in generalizing to model variability more generally). I've updated the code accordingly. Thanks!